# Google Sheets Copy a Value to Cells To the Right

Tags: google-sheets

How do I copy a value from one cell to the cells on the right if the cell to the left of the value is say the number 3?

3 | 170 |

I want to auto populate it like this

3 | 170 | 170 | 170 | 170 |

Another example

6 | 85 | 85 | 85 | 85 | 85 | 85 | 85 |

This is for a simple sales tracker so if the commission is $85 and the customer is doing a 6 month payment plan I want to spread that out into columns that will be titled with the upcoming months.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=wraprows(85,6,85)
```

OR

```js
=sequence(1,6,85,0)
```